# $("<img/>").one('load' fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using this code:

```
function CheckImage(a, i) {
    $("<img/>").one('load', function () {
        $("div.photos").append(this);
    }).attr('src',a).attr('data-photo', '0' + i);
}
```

To check if an image exists.

as an example:

```
Photo1 = 'https://imagebank.sportdirect.com/DIx.jpg_RB51,51,255,255,255,127/-/article/111108/111108-1200-01.jpg';
CheckImage(Photo1, '1');
```

It works like a charm, BUT sometimes when I load the screen using Ajax inside another screen it flickers a few times and prints the image 4 times instead of once.

Any idea where this is coming from?

Here's the ajax call for the page:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/change_item_detail?article=123',
    type:'GET',
    success: function(data){
        $("#left").html(data);
    }
});
```

Then on the `change_item_detail` page it loads this:

```
Photo1 = '1.jpg';
CheckImage(Photo1, '1');
Photo2 = '2.jpg';
CheckImage(Photo2, '2');
Photo3 = '3.jpg';
CheckImage(Photo3, '3');
Photo4 = '4.jpg';
CheckImage(Photo4, '4');
```

---

### UPDATE:

I found out it fires two times. So with 4 image check's it showes 8 images sometimes.. Any idea? Bounty will be added in a minute.

Comment: You should post relevant code regarding ajax request. I guess you are calling `CheckImage()` multiple times for some reason

Comment: @A.Wolff added the call.

Comment: Isn't this ajax request called multiple times? BTW, what does `screen` mean: `BUT sometimes when I load the screen using Ajax inside another screen`. Do you mean `window`? Iframe? Any online link to check it?

Comment: @A.Wolff it's called on a click event and thus loaded once unless I click multiple times ofcourse. The html will be loaded inside another div using ajax, so no window or iframe.

Comment: Do you potentially have the click event handler bound to more than one object that causes it to fire twice on one click?

Comment: >> $("<img/>").one('load'... << wouldn't that add a listener to every img tag on the page or actually to newly created img tag with no src? it seems to me you're listening for 'load' event on a general empty img tag.. I think you should 'append' first, then listen for 'load'.. am i missing something?

Answer (score 6):

The second event is coming from the img being inserted when you .append(this).  Try adding a class to the element to mark that has already been processed and then check this in your event handler.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (pattern)

```
        $(function() {
        function CheckImage(a, i) {
            return $("<img/>", {
              "src" : a,
              "data-photo" : "0" + i
            })
            .one("error load", function (e) {
              if (e.type === "error") {
                // if `error` `event` fired 
                // when `img`
                // `appendTo` `div.photos`,
                // `remove` `img` from DOM
                $(e.target).remove();
                console.log(e.type);
              } 
                // if no `error` `event`,
                // when `img`
                // `appendTo` `div.photos`,
                // `img` _not_ `remove` from DOM
                else {
                  console.log(e.type)
              };
             return false
            })
           .appendTo("div.photos");
        }; 

        var Photo1 = "https://imagebank.sportdirect.com/"
        + "DIx.jpg_RB51,51,255,255,255,127/"
        + "-/article/111108/111108-1200-01.jpg";

        CheckImage(Photo1, "1");
        })
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/9sK3q/

Answer (score 0):

Might the AJAX call be re-posting the

```
function CheckImage(a, i) {
    $("<img/>").one('load', function () {
        $("div.photos").append(this);
    }).attr('src',a).attr('data-photo', '0' + i);
}
```

code?

I know technically it *should* overwrite it, but when has every web browser done everything is *should* do ;)

(I've had a similar issue before where the reason was that I had the same JS file being included in my AJAX file and thus duplicate code was being sent in my AJAX, causing things to fire twice)

Answer (score 0):

If the `src` is already set then the event is firing in the cache cased before you get the event handler bound. To fix this, you can loop through checking and triggering the event based off `.complete`, like this:

```
$("img").one('load', function() {
  // do stuff
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```